# Sequence of numbers that always differ a unique value

Tags: sequences-and-series

Here is question for you from one StackOverflow member.
I'm trying to solve problem where I can always identify a change between events.
Each event is assigned an integer value, let's say 0...n

So what we do is just event(x1).value - event(x2).value != 0 in order to detect the event.

Now, we want to be able to identify the "significance" of the change based on the event values. Real example from the actual problem (which has to do with weather):

Sky conditions t0: clear
Sky conditions t1: rain
Sky conditions t2: snow
Sky conditions t3: strong winds

So, event(t0).value - event(t1).value signifies a change
event(t1).value - event(t2).value signifies another change etc

We need to have a "unique" way to identify each change based on the 
result of event(tn).value - event(tn+1).value

Any ideas?

Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $0,1,3,7,\dots 2^n-1$  All the pairwise differences are distinct.  You can use somewhat smaller numbers (there is no way to get a difference of $5$, for example), but these are easy to decode.

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much Ross.